DocBlocks activation/setup inside VSCode
I would love to make use of DocBlocks, but it seems as if my IDE does not make anything out of my DocBlocks. I know there are powerful helpers that can build up whole documentations out of DocBlocks, but for now "simple" IDE support is enough for me. How can I get there that VSCode shows some helper/info on an item (that has DocBlock-comments) on hover?
I tried out the example from an answer in this forum:
What are the comments found above methods in a controller?
I expected that VSCode would autocomplete some of the DocBlocks
@param
or
@return
but it only autocompletes.
/**
*
*/

I saw this in many examples. But I accepted that this might be a nice to have which comes with extensions only.
However I completed the following code manually.
<?php

namespace = App\Http\Controllers;

class ExampleController extends Controller {
/**
* Method accepts an instance of `MyModel` and returns
* a View responsible for displaying associated information
* 
* @param MyModel $myModel - An instance of `MyModel`
* 
* @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View
*/
  public function myMethod(MyModel $myModel) {
  return view('index', compact('myModel');
  }

  public function anotherMethod() {
  $this->MyMethod
  }
}

I expected that when hovering over "$this->MyMethod" it would show any additional help or part of the DocBlocker but it only showed up the standard autocomplete and info symbal that it is a method as it would do even without the whole DocBlocks.
Do I have to activate this inside Visual Studio?
Can you explain to me where to find this option?
Is it only available with some extension to VSCode?
At least VSCode autocompletes the Docblock exclamation... is this really all that is supported by basic VSCode?
Is there a tutorial that you would suggest for using DocBlocks inside VSCode?
I have read about possibilities to change colors and adjust DocBlocks in VSCode but I have no clue how and where to find those settings.
